# Enable google analytics for single page site with # views

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, single-page-application

I've read the similar questions, but my question is slightly different.

I am implementing a single page registration processing page for a site using Kendo UI. The site has 4 pages which was generated dynamically when user clicks menu tabs. For example, when user clicks tab1 on the menu, then `tab_1` would be injected into `app_container` container.

templates as below:

```
<div id="app_container"></div>
<script id="tab_1" type="text/x-kendo-template">
//first page
</script>
<script id="tab_2" type="text/x-kendo-template">
//second page
</script>
<script id="tab_3" type="text/x-kendo-template">
//third page
</script>
<script id="tab_4" type="text/x-kendo-template">
//fourth page
</script>
```

The page is under the domain: `www.xxxxxxxx.com/register.html`.

when user clicks the tabs in menu, then the http link address changed to this:
`www.xxxxxxxx.com/register.html#/p1`

`www.xxxxxxxx.com/register.html#/p2`

`www.xxxxxxxx.com/register.html#/p3`

`www.xxxxxxxx.com/register.html#/p4`

I've grabbed the code from GA:

```
<script>

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'xxxxxxxx.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

1) Question1, as I just only like to track this registration page, I've read google's documentation, [developers.google.com/analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages),will this codes work?

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/register.html');
```

2) Question2, how to enable GA to get data for 4 different tab pages? Do I have to modify onlick actions to track the event? or just simple track the anchor tag? I've read something from [Tracking Hash URLs](http://tizardsbriefcase.com/716/javascript/google-analytics-for-tracking-hash-urls), will this codes work for my situation? As it may take some time to show analystic, can't test it now:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', "/" + window.location.hash]);
```

where shall I put this line of code to if it is working for this single page application?

Comment: Your `push` needs to be triggered on the action. Such as, if the form is being submitted on the page, then you would capture the `submit` function and perform the push. Google fires the send event on page unload.

Comment: How long does it take for me to receive statistics?

Comment: The answer to that question varies.  But I would give it atleast a week to be properly calculating anything...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer 1:  Yes this will work perfectly fine:  `ga('send', 'pageview', '/register.html');`

You don't need the 3rd parameter if they are on the page where the code is being executed.  It will automatically grab the current page where the code is being ran from if the 3rd parameter is undefined.  But than this parameter allows you to set the page yourself, which could be useful if you need to send a pageview to a different page other than the page that the code is being executed on.

change to this:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'xxxxxxxx.com');
  ga('set', 'page', '/register.html');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

And in each tabs click event, add the corresponding code to track which tabs are clicked:

Tab 1 click event:  `ga('send', 'event', 'tab1', 'clicked');`

Tab 2 click event: `ga('send', 'event', 'tab2', 'clicked');`

Tab 3 click event: `ga('send', 'event', 'tab3', 'clicked');`

Tab 4 click event: `ga('send', 'event', 'tab4', 'clicked');`

[Source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced)

Comment: just wondering, on each page, there are some validation rules. Shall I just trigger send event when user successfully being processed to the next tab or just send event once user click the tab menu?

Comment: That's up to you how you want to track it.  You could send 2 different events, 1 for the `click` and another for the actual page `load` event.  This might be helpful if you want to determine the difference of people who clicked the tab versus those who actually waited for the tab page to load.  It's up to you how you want to do this.  Just change `'clicked'` to `'load'` or `'tab_load'` (last parameter) so you can identify between the 2 events.

Comment: Hi Solomon, appreciate your answer, however, this solution just records events. What I'd like to achieve is to make the different page shows as 'active Page'. for example, /register.html#/p1
/register.html#/p2
/register.html#/p3
/register.html#/p4

Comment: You can set multiple tracking objects and send `pageviews` on them.  Read the `Working with Multiple Tracking Objects` on the Source link in the answer:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced This is what you want to use!

Comment: Worked great. Thank you. Although if you want to track tabs or hashtags as pages its better to use 'pageview' instead of 'event'. for example ga('send', 'pageview', '/register.html#tab1');