# make google analytics tracking Hash URLs for single page application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, single-page-application

Here is my initial question: [Enable google analytics for single page site with # views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18626788/765498)

I took this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18626897/765498

However, I found that, this answer just send click events. What I'd like to achieve is that, make google analytics records different hash urls.

I read this article: [tracking hash urls](http://tizardsbriefcase.com/716/javascript/google-analytics-for-tracking-hash-urls), but have no idea how to make this happen.
I tried this codes, seems doesn't work. What I'd like to achieve is to make the different page shows as 'active Page'. for example, /register.html#/p1 and /register.html#/p2 and /register.html#/p3 and /register.html#/p4

```
  <script stype="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', "/" + window.location.hash]);
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'xxxxxxxx.com');
  ga('set','page','/register.html')
  ga('send', 'pageview');


</script>
```

Comment: According to RFC 1808: _Note that the fragment identifier (and the "#" that precedes it) is not considered part of the URL._ Using it _as part of the url_ is a misuse and therefore not reliable. You are asking for a dirty hack, do proper and clean programing.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, How would you suggest to build a single page app or site without #urls? I can't think of any 'clean or proper' way. Isn't holding on to an RFC which dates from 1995 (long before ajax and single page apps) a bit short-sighted? Mind you I don't mean this as a sneer, I'd like to know what solution you have in mind.

Comment: @Michiel You are right by saying things have changed and I read over that "single page" part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to listen for hash changes.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', "/" + window.location.hash]);
});
```

Comment: If you use `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', "/" + window.location.hash.substr(1)]);` you get rid of the # in front of the hash and (depending on the hash structure) can use the content drilldown in GA better.

Comment: and also, is it possible to restrict to listen to only register.html page? as this one page application is just within a large sites, but just only want to track register.html

Comment: Yes, then you should make sure the above script only is present on that page. You can also build in more javascript logic to track only what you want.

Comment: Thank you tom. It solved the problem..... I found it works not stable, sometimes, when I click the tabs, it just shows /register.html,but sometimes when I click the same tab, it just showed the corrent tab name...weird.